# How to add mathcal to section titles?

Tags: sectioning, mathcal

I am currently using the following code to print the section and subsection in the header.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{\textit{Page \thepage}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}
```

However, if I try to use `\mathcal` in the section titles, it causes an error. How do I get around this?

Comment: How does this differ from your earlier question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/533524 ?

Comment: Put `\protect` before `\mathcal` when the latter is used in a section (or similar) heading.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it doesn't, but no one answered my previous question

Comment: Suppose the heading is ```\section{Properties of \mathcal{S}_n}```. Where would I add ```\protect```?

Comment: `\section{Properties of \protect\mathcal{S} ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX will define `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` for you, don't force it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\itshape Page \thepage}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\quad#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\quad#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author{me}

\maketitle

\section{Test section}

\subsection{Test subsection $\mathcal{A}$}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]